# Mismatch in USB devices listed by lsusb and sys filesystem

Tags: ubuntu, usb-device, sysfs

I work on a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS PC. I have a need to find out the USB device name that matches a particular USB device ID. When I run the `lsusb` command to list USB device interfaces, here is the output I get:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 03f0:231d Hewlett-Packard Broadcom 2070 Bluetooth Combo
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:1452 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003c Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS471 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

In order to find the corresponding device names on the filesystem, I ran the following command:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d$ ls -l /sys/bus/usb/devices/
```

and got:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 1-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 1-1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 1-1.1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 1-1:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 1-1.1:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 2-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 2-1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 2-1:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 2-1.6 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 2-1.6:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 2-1.6:1.1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 2-1.6:1.2 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 2-1.6:1.3 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 3-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:26:00.0/usb3/3-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 3-1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:26:00.0/usb3/3-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 3-1:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:26:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 3-1:1.1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:26:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 3-1:1.2 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:26:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 4-0:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:26:00.0/usb4/4-0:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 usb1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 usb2 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 usb3 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:26:00.0/usb3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 20 20:24 usb4 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:26:00.0/usb4
```

As you can see, *there is no match whatsoever between the device IDs listed in the outputs of the above two commands*. Are there any inaccuracies here? How do I find out the matching device IDs, and hence the corresponding device names?

Comment: I'm seeing something like this too, furthermore I've got 2 integrated USB webcams in my Lenovo and one of them is an infrared one - for some reason the normal stops working in *some* applications and the IR has the same bus-device number in  `/sys` as the normal in lsusb... :F